# Xamarin.Forms embed native View in xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a Xamarin.Forms Page which should display a specific View (in this case, it is a View from Lottie.Forms) but because it does not support UWP, I need to use a different Library for this (LottieUWP) which is a native one. So Iif the platform is UWP, I want to display the View inside LottieUWP. Is there a way to achieve this directly inside my portable project?

Comment: Two options that could work. Using the same syntax and methodology you can reference your UWP head and try to reference the Lottie view you need. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml Or a Custom Renderer will definitely work. Using OnPlatform may be needed.

Comment: I did it with a custom renderer, thanks